# How to check IS against multiple types

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a better way to write this code? Seems like Kotlin should be able to get me a cleaner version, but I cannot figure it out.

```
    override fun onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment)

        if (fragment is Step1Fragment) {
            fragment.assignActivity(this)
            return
        }
        if (fragment is Step2Fragment) {
            fragment.assignActivity(this)
            return
        }
        if (fragment is Step3Fragment) {
            fragment.assignActivity(this)
            return
        }
        if (fragment is Step4Fragment) {
            fragment.assignActivity(this)
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could make an interface that is implemented by fragments you wish to do this with and then just check if it's an instance of that interface.

Comment: I'll give that a try

Comment: Can you please explain the reason to behind the `assignActivity()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create an interface.

```
interface ActivityAssignable {
    fun assignActivity(activity: Activity)
}
```

Step 2: Make your fragments implement that interface.

```
class Step1Fragment: Fragment(), ActivityAssignable {
    override fun assignActivity(activity: Activity) { ... }
}

class Step2Fragment: Fragment(), ActivityAssignable {
    override fun assignActivity(activity: Activity) { ... }
}
```

Step 3: Use that interface in your if statement

```
if (fragment is ActivityAssignable) {
    fragment.assignActivity(this)
}
```

Step 4: PROFIT!